# applying .astype() for specific indices doesn't work

Tags: python, numpy

I want to change first column to int in dnarray

```
print(gcp)
```

> [[ 1.     6.218  2.974  0.   ]  [ 2.    32.881  8.66   0.   ]  [ 3.
>   38.94  35.843  0.   ]  [ 4.     8.52  35.679  0.   ]  [ 5.    52.902 49.538  0.   ]]

```
print(gcp.dtype)
```

> float64

```
gcp[:,0] = (gcp[:,0]).astype(int)
print(((gcp[:,0]).astype(int)).dtype)
```

> int32

```
print(gcp.dtype)
```

> float64

I tried to use deepcopy, but no success.
Any help will be good, I didn't find any similar questions.

Comment: You can't convert one column in a float array to integer.  You will have to create a structured array or recarray (named fields) if you want an array with mixed dtypes.

Comment: As NaN suggested you need to use numpy records. The ndarray is supposed to have all elements in all n dimensions to have same type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To have just the `index of the row(+1)` as element of the array seems redundant to me, maybe you don't need the first row at all.
Otherwise the best option to me is to use two arrays:

```
gcp0 = gcp[:, 0].astype(int)
gcp = gcp[:, 1:]
```

Another possibility is to define separate `named fields` with respective `dtypes` for the separate columns, which brings you maybe closer to `pandas`, which is another option you have.

```
gcp = np.array([(1., 6.218,  2.974,  0.),
                (2., 32.881, 8.66,   0.),
                (3., 38.94,  35.843, 0.),
                (4., 8.52,   35.679, 0.),
                (5., 52.902, 49.538, 0.)],
                dtype={'names':   ['index', 'a0', 'a1', 'a2'],
                       'formats': [int, float, float, float]})

print(gcp['index'])
# [1 2 3 4 5]
```